# Convert this .htaccess to nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am having some problems trying to translate this to nginx, today I can't make my brain to work well and solve this!

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   $1                 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php?url=$1   [QSA,L]
```

Comment: https://nginx.org/r/try_files

Comment: What have you tried? Are you having trouble understanding the current Apache rules or writing the new Nginx rules?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the apache rule, but I ended up modifying a little bit the PHP code and made all work. Just sent all to index.php with an nginx rule and the process the urls there.

Comment: The question that I linked to above in comments shows the solution you would require to mimic these rules in Nginx. Whilst that other question has slightly different-looking Apache directives, the result is the same.